# Weight decay loss

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I need to write a code to gradually decay the weight of my loss function by computes lambda with given steps, But I don't have any idea. Any help will be appreciated.

This is my Loss function:

```
loss_A = criterion(recov_A, real_A)
loss_Final = lambda_A * loss_A + #lambda_A is a fixed number: 10
```

I don't want the lambda_A to be fixed. I need to gradually decay the lambda after passing the specified number of steps

```
# write function that computes lambda given the steps
cur_lambda  = compute_lambda(step, decay_params, initial_lamdba) 
Loss_Final = cur_lambda * loss_A
```

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367) and [edit] your post. It is better to post your approach as [mcve] an tell us why/how it is not sufficient.

Comment: My question is obvious and is not too broad to edit my post. I don’t think needs further information. I want to gradually decay the weight (lambda_A) of my loss function instead of having fixes weight loss.

Comment: Your problem is not obvious to me :) the obvoious solution is: count the rounds you are doing and add a dampening term that reduces the influx of the error function - nothing in your code shows the efford to do that nor where the problem with this (or any other choice of solutions you tried) is .. the code is not runnable as is so there is not much one can do with it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To decay the fixed number depends on the number of steps or even the number of epochs you can use the following code or you can write the code as a function and call it whenever you want.

```
final_value = 1e-3 # Small number because dont end up with 0 
initial_value = 20
starting_step = 25 
total_step = 100
for i in range(total_step):
  if i <= starting_step:
     print(i, initial_value)
  else:
    print (i, initial_value + i * (final_value-initial_value)/total_step)
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution:

```
l = lambda r: 1 if r < 10 else 1.0-(r-9)/10.0  # 1 for r in 0..9, then less then 1 down to 0

value = 20
for r in range(20):
    print (r,":", value * l(r))  # multiply your loss with round-based lambda factor
```

Output:

```
0 : 20
1 : 20
2 : 20
3 : 20
4 : 20
5 : 20
6 : 20
7 : 20
8 : 20
9 : 20
10 : 18.0
11 : 16.0
12 : 14.0
13 : 12.0
14 : 10.0
15 : 8.0
16 : 6.000000000000001
17 : 3.999999999999999
18 : 1.9999999999999996
19 : 0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the obvious solution :). But this is not what I want. Would you please look at this question maybe give you better idea what I want I explained more there.  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54047725/gradually-decay-the-weight-of-loss-function] and Also I dont want to get 0.0

Comment: @Kenzo You can modify the dampening term `l = lambda r: 1 if r < 10 else 1.0-(r-9)/10.0` as you like .. f.e. `l = lambda r: max(1 if r < 10 else 1.0-(r-9)/10.0, 0.1234)` to reduce it minimally to 0.1234 ... or however you want to go - you can change it as you like. Maybe someone will give you a better aproach though

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :)